# Security implications of adding nobody to docker group

Tags: linux, docker

A docker monitoring tool needs read access to the docker socket in order to collect stats. The [setup instructions](https://www.librato.com/docs/kb/collect/integrations/docker/) asks me to provide "Read-only access to the Docker socket" by running the following

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker nobody
```

Is this a safe thing to do?

Comment: What a good idea! ... Hem no.... It's a not so good idea! User *nobody* could only be member of *nogroup*!

Comment: This would be a supplemental group. The primary group is indeed _nogroup_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nobody` user was originally used for NFS. However people started using it to run daemons that did not need to run as root. This was fine when used by just one daemon, but it is no longer recommended when multiple daemons are running as that user. Linux only provides *inter*-user isolation, not *intra*-user isolation, meaning user X and user Y cannot tamper with each other's processes, but one process running as user X can tamper with another process running as user X. If Docker is running as the this user, anything running as the same user will be able to compromise it, for example by attaching debuggers and modifying memory via `ptrace()` and similar syscalls, sending signals via `kill()` or `fcntl()`, or even changing resource limits via `prlimit64()`.

**The recommended solution is to run an unprivileged daemon under its *own* user or group.**